# How do you work with include pages in jsp or php or the likes without getting IDE / Editor warnings for CSS classes?

Tags: html, jsp, netbeans

If the CSS files for your site are referenced in the parent page, obviously you can use those CSS rules and classes in the sub-page or "included" page (like a jsp include or a php include).  That will run as expected in the browser.  BUT, if you are using an IDE or smart text editor of some kind (I'm using Netbeans), you will get warnings about the CSS elements in the sub-page (a .jspf for example) unless that file has a redundant reference to the css files.  Is there a work-around for this? I don't want to have to reference the CSS files in both my jsp and my jspf (jsp include).

Answer (score 0):

One technique I've used is to abandon jspf files in favour of a templating system where if you want to include something from a template, the template is actually a full page of which part is marked to be included.  I actually use a home-grown template system for this, but my understanding is that thymeleaf (http://www.thymeleaf.org/) offers the same feature.